# command find with -or and exec malfunctioning

Tags: macos, find, command-line-interface

If I execute

```
find . -name "*FOO*" -or -name "*foo*"
```

It works perfectly, returning 106 files with the upper-case FOO and 4 files with the lower-case foo.

If I add the exec ls syntax like this

```
find . -name "*FOO*" -or -name "*foo*"  -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

it *only returns the 4 with the lower-case foo*

If I execute the exact same command on a real Unix host, it returns both the upper and lower, exactly as I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just operator precedence - try:

```
find . \( -name "*FOO*" -or -name "*foo*" \) -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Interesting that it operates differently on OSX vs. Unix.  When I get home, I will try it on Linux.

Comment: Sometimes there are differences between BSD and non-BSD OSes, but I'm guessing you may have a case insensitive (but case preserving) file system in one case, e.g. OS X HFS+. Anyway, if you respect the usual rules of operator precedence it should work the same everywhere.